# Error including jpeglib.h: expected identifier before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, libjpeg

I'm trying to build [bundler_sfm](https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm) on my Fedora 25 machine, but get the following errors when compiling the `LoadJPEG.cpp` file:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:27:0,
                 from LoadJPEG.cpp:23:
/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:704:3: error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
   JMETHOD(noreturn_t, error_exit, (j_common_ptr cinfo));
   ^
/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:704:3: error: ‘noreturn_t’ declared as function returning a function
   JMETHOD(noreturn_t, error_exit, (j_common_ptr cinfo));
   ^
```

It seems as though my compiler somehow doesn't like the `jpeglib.h` header file, but I can't figure out why. Here is the command in the makefile that generates the error:

```
g++ -c -o LoadJPEG.o -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-result -std=gnu++0x \
-I../lib/imagelib -I../lib/sfm-driver -I../lib/matrix -I../lib/5point \
-I../lib/sba-1.5 -I../lib/ann_1.1_char/include -I../include  \
-D__NO_UI__ -D__BUNDLER__ -D__BUNDLER_DISTR__ LoadJPEG.cpp
```

And here is the location in `jpeglib.h` in question:

```
700 /* Error handler object */
701 
702 struct jpeg_error_mgr {
703   /* Error exit handler: does not return to caller */
704   JMETHOD(noreturn_t, error_exit, (j_common_ptr cinfo));
705   /* Conditionally emit a trace or warning message */
706   JMETHOD(void, emit_message, (j_common_ptr cinfo, int msg_level));
707   /* Routine that actually outputs a trace or error message */
708   JMETHOD(void, output_message, (j_common_ptr cinfo));
```

I don't know if this matters, but the `jpeglib.h` file is enclosed within an `extern "C" {` block.

I opened [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm/issues/51) on the bundler_sfm repo, but it seems my problem is probably not specific to that project. If anyone can tell what is going wrong here, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are there other errors before this one? Is this the only compiler output?

Comment: @cdhowie, there are errors after this where the compiler complains that several of the `jpeglib.h` functions are not being used correctly, e.g.:

`LoadJPEG.cpp:32:37: error: too many arguments to function ‘jpeg_error_mgr* jpeg_std_error()’`

The two errors at the top of the question are the only errors within `jpeglib.h` that the compiler reports.

Comment: The source package builds successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 using the `libjpeg`
dev package provided by the package manager. Apparently you are
using a `libjpeg`, including `jpeglib.h`, that you built yourself,
since it is installed under `/usr/local`. Your build of `libjpeg`
may therefore be at fault. You might have better luck removing it
and installing `libjpeg-devel` from your package manager.